# Redirecting Ascx page

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to redirect an ascx page using

```
Response.Redirect();
```

My code is

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/postauthenticated/employeereprintw2requestconfirmtest.ascx");
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. An ASCX control cannot live alone. It should always be hosted in a WebForm (ASPX). And you can only redirect to WebForms or generic handlers. Actually only to generic handlers which are the basic entry points for web requests. The WebForms is just a custom generic handler.

Answer (score 2):

No its not possible. We can not redirect to .ascx. In short .ascx is not page to redirect. Its a user control. If we need to use  it,we have to put it on any page and then only it can be visible in the browser. We never use .ascx as stand alone.

Answer (score 2):

No, It is not possible to redirect to a user control by using `Response.Redirect();` because a user control (.ascx) is just a partial page not a complete page to which you can redirect your controls. A user control cannot exist alone without a WebForm. So a user control (.ascx) always needed to register itself in a WebForm (.aspx) before accessing it. 
One WebForm (.aspx page) can have multiple user controls (.ascx) as they are partial pages. So multiple user controls can be registered on One WebForm in ASP.NET.