# Ascx page not loading into browser

Tags: asp.net

I have a .ascx page in when I redirect from another page, page_Oninit and Page_load events are occured and all controls loaded with initializecomponents().

But the page is not showing in the browser. Do you have any idea why this occur?

Comment: ASCX isn't a page, it's a user control.  It can't be loaded by itself as a page.  Something it looks like you should already know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011190/redirecting-ascx-page

Comment: `.ascx` are not pages, but controls. Is your question asking why is the `.aspx` page not loading? `.ascx` controls are hosted inside of pages.

Comment: An `.ascx` page is "A Web user control file that defines a custom functionality that you can add to any ASP.NET Web Forms page" - MSDN.  These file types can NOT be loaded by themselves as a page.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But we can load the .ascx control via handler, am I correct?

Comment: its a child page it cant render with our parent

Answer (score 1):

.ASCX is user control. When we add it into our page say 'Default.aspx' it becomes the part of that page but not whole page. So you can not use .ASCX as standalone. If you want to see it,you have to place it into some page and then only you can view it from browser.